# Python - Best Way to Get Mode With Scipy And Have Clean Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, statistics

```py
import statistics
import scipy

# I would like to do this with scipy.
print(statistics.mode([1, 2, 3]))
# returns 1, I would like 'no mode'

print([statistics.mode([1, 1, 2, 3, 3]))
# returns 1, I would like [1, 3]
```

I am looking for the best solution to this problem, currently, I'm just using the basic statistics package, but I would like to be able to do this with the scipy package, but `scipy.stats.mode` doesn't give me what I would want. Both of these packages don't give me what I'm looking for.

Comment: According to the scipy documentation, the underlying code uses `np.unique`. You should be able to write your own code to do what you need since Scipy only returns one value if there are multiple modes.

Answer (score 1):

I've found one way, example

```py
import statistics

print(statistics.multimode([1, 2, 3]))
# returns [1, 2, 3]
print(statistics.multimode([1, 1, 2, 3])
# returns [1]
```

It doesn't use scipy, but it's still good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections Counter` as well.

In `statistics.mode`, collections Counter is used under the hood.

```
from collections import Counter as c
lst = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]

print(c(lst)

Counter({1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2})  # here keys are the elements of the list and values are  the frequencies of those respective elements.
```

---

```
c(lst).most_common(2)  #will give 2 elements with highest number of occurrence.

[(1, 2), (3, 2)]       # 1 and 3 both occurs 2 times
```

---

Now, to find multimode:

```
[k for k, v in c(lst).items() if v == c(lst).most_common(1)[0][1]]

#output
[1, 3]
```